# Run command when opening a file of a specific filetype

Tags: hooks, files, major-mode

I'm trying to get a lisp script to run some commands for me when I open a file of a specific filetype. I know that I'm working in the correct init file because if I remove the theme from it, emacs has no theme when I start it up.

This is the script I'm using which doesn't work (no errors or anything):

```
(defun my-project-hook (filename)
  (when (string= (file-name-extension filename) "ts")
    ((typescript-mode)
     (tss-setup-current-buffer))
  ) 
)

(add-hook 'after-load-functions 'my-project-hook)
```

Comment: In this context, "load" means "load as lisp code". I think you want find-file-hook instead (note that these are not called with an argument ! use buffer-file-name instead). You may also like to use auto-mode-alist and define your own major mode.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you want a mode hook.

Comment: You haven't hit the issue yet because your function doesn't run but when it does you know that the above is not valid lisp. The body of your `when` call is malformed. The two function calls cannot be surrounded with parenthesis like they are. Note the difference between your code and @sds's

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Emacs terminology, these are two different steps:

- Associate files with the `.ts` extension with the [major mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes) `typescript-mode`.
- Run the function `tss-setup-current-buffer` when Typescript mode starts.

To choose [which major mode to use](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#index-magic_002dmode_002dalist) for certain file names, add an entry to the variable `auto-mode-alist`. Put the following line in your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ts\\'" . typescript-mode))
```

`\.ts\'` is a regular expression that matches file names with the `.ts` extension.

To run the function `tss-setup-current-buffer` whenever Typescript mode starts (I presume that you want to run it even for Typescript mode files that don't have the `.ts` extension), add it to the Typescript mode startup [hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks).

```
(add-hook 'typescript-mode-hook 'tss-setup-current-buffer)
```

Depending on how you installed `typescript.el` and `tss.el`, you may also need to declare that the functions `typescript-mode` and `tss-setup-current-buffer` have to be loaded from those files. This avoids having to load `typescript.el` and `tss.el` as soon as Emacs start: they will be loaded on demand, when you first open a `.ts` file or run `typescript-mode` explicitly.

```
(autoload 'typescript-mode "Major mode for typescript files" t)
(autoload 'tss-setup-current-buffer "Set up the current file for TSS" t)
```

Comment: I am trying to hook `magit-status` but it prevent me to file that I want to open

Answer (score 11):

What you are looking for is [`find-file-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html#Visiting-Functions):

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-project-hook)
(defun my-project-hook ()
  (when (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "ts")
    (typescript-mode)
    (tss-setup-current-buffer)))
```

Comment: While that will work, it should be pointed out that this is not the correct way to start up major modes when finding a file or to set up customizations for the major mode. The `auto-mode-alist` should be used to determine when to startup typescript-mode, and a `typescript-mode-hook` should be used to run `tss-setup-current-buffer`.

Comment: Using `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ts\\'" . typescript-mode))` and
`(add-hook 'typescript-mode-hook 'tss-setup-current-buffer)` would be the normal way to do it.