# Executing a function when opening a file of certain type

Tags: elisp, hooks, files

I would like that when I open a file of certain type (say `*.abc`)
certain function (say `my-function`) automatically executes at the
opening.

**Edit**. The function is a buffer-dependent function and should run at the buffer containing the file
  `*.abc`, i.e., it should run after loading the file
  `.abc` not before.

The function I would like to execute is
  `shr-render-buffer` (but it may arise for other functions). It
  renders html codes. Note that the file may have an arbitrary suffix
  not just `.html`

After the hints in the answer of Mark an using the links in my comment
below it, I tried the following:

Attempt 1:

```el
(require 'shr)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-function)
(defun my-function ()
  (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "\\.html\\'" buffer-file-name))
             '(shr-render-buffer)))
```

Attempt 2:

```el
(require 'shr)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.abc\\'" . (lambda ()
                              '(shr-render-buffer))))
```

Attempt 3:

```el
(require 'shr)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-function)
(defun my-function ()
  (when (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "abc")
    '(shr-render-buffer)
    ))
```

Then after the suggetion of Lidydancer, I tried to define a major mode for
`.abc` types. For simplicity I considered them as `html-mode` and I
used the following (already provided by one of the answers in the
below links):

Attempt 4:

```el
(require 'shr)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.abc\\'" . html-mode))
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'shr-render-buffer)
```

All my attempts were unsuccessful.

Comment: Is there some associated major mode for this sort of files? Something like `abc-mode`?

Comment: @Mark No, there is no major mode for this sort of files.

Comment: Why not define your own major mode, say `abc-mode`, and add your function to `abc-mode-hook`?

Comment: @Lindydancer, the problem is that even by defining an `abc-mode` the problem persists, i.e., the function executes *before* displaying of buffer (for example take the example where `my-function` is `split-window-vertically`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt 1 is almost correct. Your attempt 3 will also work with the same fixes I have done below.

Here are the two things that needed to be fixed:

1. You do not quote the function you are calling. If you want to call function `FN`, you simply do `(FN)`. When you do `'(FN)` it simply is a list with one element: the symbol `FN`.
2. You were missing a mandatory argument that `shr-render-buffer` needed; you need to specify which buffer you want that function to act upon.

Here's something I quickly tried out and works:

```el
(require 'shr)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-function)
(defun my-function ()
  (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "\\.html\\'" buffer-file-name))
    (shr-render-buffer (current-buffer)))) ; FIXED line
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find-file-hook`. From doc-string:

> List of functions to be called after a buffer is loaded from a file.
>   The buffer's local variables (if any) will have been processed before the
>   functions are called.

Thus, you can do this:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'your-function)
```

In `your-function` your should test if `buffer-file-name` has the extension you target. Then you can execute some code.

There may be better solution I don't know of.

Comment: Your idea can be used in certain circumstances (for example when
`my-function` is `(message "yes")`). But there are the situations where I have no control on the content of
`my-function`.

Comment: Apart from this, using your idea and some similar questions given in
http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12396/ and
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6886643/
I tried to do by writing `(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-function)
(defun my-function ()
  (when (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "abc")
(end-of-buffer)
    ))
` it when `my-function` is
 `end-of-buffer` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Similarly when `my-function2` is `split-window-vertically` I wrote `(defun my-function2 ()
  (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "\\.abc\\'" buffer-file-name))
      (split-window-vertically)
    )
  )

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-function2)
` does not split the window of the file `.abc` instead it split the
window in one half is `.abc` and in the other half is `scratch` buffer.

Comment: @Name, ah, problem here is that this hook is called *before* displaying of buffer. Take a look at `display-buffer-alist`, this might help you to do what you want to do, although it's pretty hairy.

Comment: @Name, also, it feels like XY problem, could you describe your final aim?

Comment: What you said is exactly what I want to do, i.e., executing the command *after* displaying of buffer.

Comment: @Name It will help if you update the question with what you tried and didn't work. What is the function that you are trying to call after displaying the buffer?