# Org-Mode Startup not Rendering Theme Colors at Startup

Tags: org-mode

### System Info

- Windows 10
- emacs 27.1 64-bit

### Description

Basically, when I open a new org file, it appears to be a plain text document.  However, I can clearly see that org-mode is activated, and this is confirmed by `M-x describe-variable major-mode`.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, I don't see any coloring of my example headlines despite clearly being in Org-Mode.  However, once I `M-x org-mode`, the colors are rendered.  How do I go about debugging?

Another weird thing I noticed in my message buffer was the following line: (Shell command succeeded with no output).  I've never seen this before, so I don't know if it's related.  Google searches don't yield anything helpful.

Comment: Try `C-u C-x =` with your cursor on a character in the headline and see what the resulting output says about text properties. E.g. does it say that the face is `org-level-1`? It may be that the faces are not set, or it may be that the faces are set but the fontification fails. This might help to narrow things down a bit. Also, what happens if you do `M-x org-mode` by hand? Does it look better? Does it fail? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  When I do `M-x org-mode` then the colors are then applied.

Comment: @NickD yes- as my post explains. M-X org-mode produces the colors and everything works fine.  It's just that I'd like to have the colors render when I open my file

Comment: So do you have an entry for Org mode files in your `auto-mode-alist`?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, I found that `ol-docview` try to find some non existing executables, remove `ol-docview` from `org-modules` solved my problem.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a long time. And, indeed, it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple work-around that runs `org-mode` when an `*.org` is opened.  It uses the information found in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12401

Though I don't believe this is a good fix as there must be something not right that the colors are not being applied.  Anyhow, I added this to my `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-org-mode-file-hook)
(defun my-org-mode-file-hook ()
  (when (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "org")
    (org-mode)))
```

Comment: As the details in my post explains, I am indeed in "org-mode" when I open my files.  it's just that the colors are not rendering.  Also, there is a much more elegant way to reproduce what you're trying to do via:

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))

Comment: Yeah, I have the exact same problem as you do, down to the message "Shell command succeeded with no output".  Too, I am in "org-mode" when the file opens, but without any colors.  This was my simple solution to not having to do `M-x org-mode` each time I open an org file. I'll probably monitor this question for a legit solution and will edit my answer pointing to the real solution once it appears.

Comment: @treefiddy I am also getting a "File exists but cannot be read" message when opening files from a network drive.  But then it opens after about 5 seconds(!)